# Как работает механизм обновления токенов на сервере?

Tags: oauth2

При использовании Oauth2 протокола авторизации для клиента создается уникальный токен. С течением времени токены обновляются на сервера в целях безопасности.

В связи с этим вопрос: какой механизм для этого используется? (скрипт, системный процесс).

Comment: любой, совсем любой

Comment: Из распространненой практики - обычно это что?